# @Autowired dependency injection in @Aspect is null for LoggerContext

Tags: java, spring, aop, logback

My simple application working fine before adding LoggingAspectConfiguration class. Source code is as follows: (removed import statements)

This is the top class

```
package com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration;

public class ApplicationInitialization extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { ApplicationRootClassConfiguration.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { ApplicationWebConfiguration.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
  }
}
```

This is application root class where componentscan present

```
package com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.backend;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.general", "com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.backend", "com.rsa.tools.springmvc.dao", "com.rsa.tools.springmvc.service"})
public class ApplicationRootClassConfiguration {
}
```

Logback configuration

```
package com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.general;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationLogbackConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public LoggerContext getLoggerContext() { ... }
}
```

Till here it works fine.

After I added the following class:

```
package com.rsa.tools.springmvc.configuration.general;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspectConfiguration {
  @Autowired
  LoggerContext loggerCtx;

  @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(..))")
  protected void loggingOperation() {}

  @Before("loggingOperation()")
  @Order(1)
  public void logJoinPoint(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Logger logger = loggerCtx.getLogger(this.getClass());
    logger.trace("Join point kind : " + joinPoint.getKind());
    logger.info("Signature declaring type : "+ joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
    logger.info("Signature name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    logger.info("Arguments : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    logger.info("Target class : "+ joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
    logger.info("This class : " + joinPoint.getThis().getClass().getName());
  }
  ...
}
```

I started seeing Null pointer exception because for loggerCtx dependency injection did not work. How to address this issue?

Comment: Is `@Order` the annotation from spring? Why do you have it on the `logJoinPoint` method?

Comment: I removed it, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aspect is created outside spring container.

Instead of creating LoggingAspectConfiguration as a component try it creating as bean in ApplicationLogbackConfiguration  (which is a configuration class)

create a setter method inside LoggingAspectConfiguration for LoggerContext

```
@Bean
public LoggingAspectConfiguration getLoggerContext(LoggerContext  context) 
{
LoggingAspectConfiguration aspect = new LoggingAspectConfiguration();
aspect.setLoggerContext (context)
return aspect;  
}
```

Spring container autowiresLoggerContext by type (or you can have @Autowired annotation in that method parameter. ).

Comment: What is "a" here? How to specify Aspect if I create it as a @Bean inside ApplicationLogbackConfiguration? You said setter method. Code sample is for getter method. I am missing something here.

Comment: Typo corrected. As I said aspect is outside container and t  loggercontext is a spring bean and this let the container know that the bean is an aspect when it loads it and thereby it also sets loggercontext.